# Trouble with Querying an XML document in VB

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm working with XML for the first time in a VB project. I've been working on this query for 3 hours and reading up on it but I've had no luck, I don't think I really understand the specific terminology to get this query to work properly with my document.

The issue is that I keep returning nothing and causing a crash. I've messed around with the code so much now and it probably works less than the original bit I wrote, but you should be able to get the gist, it's probably painful to see for anyone with XML experience! It's just part of my preferences which stores the correct provider for different versions of Access and allows for more versions to be added by the user once the program has been delivered. Here's the code, for what it's worth.

Here I'm wanting to find the value of the 'string' where the version's 'name' is equal to the test value of "Access 2010"

```
Dim xml As XDocument = XDocument.Load("preferences.xml")
    Dim query = From xe In xml.Descendants("Accessversion")
        Where xe.Element("Version").Attribute("Name") = "Access 2010"
        Select xe.Element("string").Value
```

And this is the relevent section of the XML document:

```
<Preferences>

  <AccessVersion>
    <Version>
        <Name>Access 97</Name>
        <string>Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0</string>
    </Version>
    <Version>
        <Name>Access 2000</Name>
        <string>Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0</string>
    </Version>
    <Version>
        <Name>Access 2002</Name>
        <string>Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0</string>
    </Version>
    <Version>
        <Name>Access 2003</Name>
        <string>Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0</string>
    </Version>
    <Version>
        <Name>Access 2007</Name>
        <string>Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0</string>
    </Version>
    <Version>
        <Name>Access 2010</Name>
        <string>"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"</string>
    </Version>
    <Version>
        <Name>Access 2013</Name>
        <string>Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0</string>
    </Version>
  </AccessVersion>
```

Again, I realise this probably isn't the best way to apply XML, but I've had to learn it in about an hour for part of this project. As you can probably tell, I'm very new to programming, the rest of the project has gone really well, but this really has me stumped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim xml As XDocument = XDocument.Load("preferences.xml")
Dim query = From xe In xml.Descendants("Version")
            Where xe.Element("Name").Value = "Access 2010"
            Select xe.Element("string").Value
```

Comment: Many thanks, that's just saved me a massive headache! All about the sytax!

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it clear what was wrong with your query, following is the right version of your approach :

```
Dim query = From xe In xml.Descendants("Accessversion")
        Where xe.Element("Version").Element("Name").Value = "Access 2010"
        Select xe.Element("Version").Element("string").Value
```

Note that `.Descendants` will search all elements under current tag. And `.Element` will search only direct childs of current element. And keep in mind that `xe` is `<Accessversion>` tag in this case.

But anyway @Iomed's answer is a better/simpler approach